# How to get all factory_girl factories defined for a particular model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec3

I have a factory defined in `<Rails-root>/spec/factories/models.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    id 1
    association :organization, factory: :aureso
    name "Default Model"

    factory :serie_1 do
      id 2
      name 'serie_1'
    end

    factory :serie_2 do
      id 3
      name 'serie_2'
    end

    factory :serie_3 do
      id 4
      name 'serie_3'
    end
  end
end
```

I want to get all the factories defined for Class `Model`.

I can get factory definitions for all classes with `FactoryGirl.factories`, and yes, I can achieve the above using map/reduce. But I want to know if there is any helper method to get all definitions for a model class.

Comment: i really don't understand what are you talking about. Factory is basically a object representing a certain model. ActiveModel Model is a class that includes validations and other plain ruby things, and it is part of ActiveRecord::Base class, from which model inherits. If you are speaking about some shared logic between all factories, you can use traits.

Comment: you should create different factories for different models. remove `id` attribute, because id creates by database.

Comment: I am using fixture-builder (https://github.com/rdy/fixture_builder) and I want id to be self defined which is useful for sequencing. That's not causing me any problem. I just wanted to know is there a way to get all factories referencing to a model class in this case :model(class name Model).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As one can see from [the source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/v4.5.0/lib/factory_girl.rb), the `FactoryGirl` class in the current version of factory_girl (4.5.0) does not have a convenient way to list the factories that create instances of a given class.

That's not a very exciting answer, so let's do it the inconvenient way! `FactoryGirl.factories` returns a [`FactoryGirl::Registry`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/v4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb), which again doesn't have a convenient way to list factories but does have an `@items` hash whose keys are factory names and whose values are instances of [`FactoryGirl::Factory`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/v4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb). The class which a given `Factory` builds instances of is returned by `Factory#build_class`. So we can list the factories that build instances of a given class with

```
FactoryGirl.
  factories.
  instance_variable_get('@items').
  select { |name, factory| factory.build_class == SomeClass }.
  keys
```

Since that relies on internals, it's sure to break in the future.

Comment: Nice.Thanks for `@items`. Can you locate me to the source code(or doc.) where the instance variable is mentioned ?

Comment: I did! Follow the link to `FactoryGirl::Registry`.

Comment: Since `FactoryBot::Registry` is an `Enumerable` of [`Factories`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/FactoryBot/Factory), you can do this without accessing `@items` (although it still uses undocumented APIs): `FactoryBot.factories.select { |f| f.build_class == SomeClass }.map(&:name)`